# PHP Cookie setlang

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have the following code on settings.php page:

```
define('APP_PATH',  realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('APP_LANG',  APP_PATH . '/lang');

require_once 'Zend/Translate.php';

$locale = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'ro'; // default language
$translate = new Zend_Translate( array( 'adapter' => 'csv', 'content' => APP_LANG, 'scan'     => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY ) );
$translate->setLocale($locale);
```

I change language using following code:

```
<a href="?lang=en">EN</a>
<a href="?lang=ro">RO</a>
```

I want to use cookies to save user language on click, but im stucked..

I've tryed so many lines of codes, but unsuccesfully.

Can someone explain me how to resolve that problem?

I apreciate any help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To set the lang cookie:

```
<?php
$lang = 'en';
setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
```

To get the lang cookie:

```
<?php
$lang = !isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ? 'en' : $_COOKIE['lang'];
```

That's all :)

Comment: Thank you for your response my friend.. Im newbie on PHP , so i will try to edit my code with your's .. Ty you again.. Cheers!